# stop deleting records in one2many relationship in odoo

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9, odoo-10

I have created relational columns with different class but when i delete relational records it will delete records from the base class as well.

Anyone have any solution to stop deleting the records from the base class while deleting relational field.

I have checked with `ondelete='set null'` on field declaration.

e.g i have create a field many2one with 'purchase.order', when i delete this record it delete the 'purchase.order' as well.

I want to stop deleting the purchase order while delete the record.

Comment: try ondelete='restrict' or ondelete='cascade'

Comment: @ADVALAKI I have try with both

Comment: Did you try my answer?

Comment: @CherifOdoo Yes, I tried it, I vote up... Thanks !!!

Answer (score 2):

in order to stop the field one2many from deleting record witch is the default behavior of that field is when you creating you view give it an option:

```xml
<field name="one2many_field_name" options="{'not_delete': True}" />
```

Answer (score 1):

In Odoo 8, use `widget="many2many"`:

```xml
<field name="one2many_field_name" widget="many2many" />
```